# Convert the class to logical of multiple variables in the workspace

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have some logical values being read in as characters from some data, which is being imported in bulk along with other variables, otherwise I would have changed their class at the beginning:

library(tidyverse)

```
switch_1 <- "TRUE"
switch_2 <- "FALSE"
switch_49 <- "FALSE"
switch_50 <- "TRUE"
```

I would like to convert these to logical using some kind of elegant loop (as there are many switches)

So far I have tried:

```
ls() %>%
str_subset("switch") %>%
map(get) %>%
map(as.logical)
```

Which converts them to the correct format, but doesn't re-assign their values within the workspace.

How can I re-assign their value in the workspace?

```
> ls() %>% str_subset("switch_") %>% map(get) %>% map(as.logical)
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE

[[4]]
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Without wanting to be the "don't start from there" guy - why do you have multiple objects being read in as the wrong type?  Can we go back and address how they are imported instead?  Ideally, they should be imported with the right type and into a list or other structure which will make further manipulation much easier.

Comment: Fair point, this data is provided to the code externally through some .csv files. There are lots of parameters to import so this is done once, from a single file using
```walk2(variable, value, ~assign(.x, .y, envir = .GlobalEnv)))```

Answer (score 2):

Note: this works but I don't think you should do it.  It is very prone to messing things up if there is an unexpectedly named object in the global environment.

Change the `map()` to a custom function which `get`s the value, makes it `as.logical` and then `assign`s it back in the global environment, overwriting its old value/type.

```
ls() %>%
  str_subset("switch") %>%
  map(\(x) { assign(x, as.logical(get(x)), envir = globalenv()) } )
```

gives

```
> switch_1
[1] TRUE
```

### A possibly better approach:

I prefer this, which has the same issue of trawling the global environment at first but at least contains the results:

```
switches <- mget(ls(pattern = '^switch_')) %>% lapply(as.logical)
switches
$switch_1
[1] TRUE

$switch_2
[1] FALSE

$switch_49
[1] FALSE

$switch_50
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful. I'll go for the second option. And I also didn't know you could do that with assign!